# "the witness that testifies for passing of time." Why *for* instead of *the*?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, definite-articles

I have the sentence below:

> "History is the witness that __________ passing of time."
>
> a. testifies the
> b. testifies for
> c. will testify for
> d. be meeting

I confidently answered ***a***, but the correct answer is ***b***. Why is it? Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: "History is the witness that testifies for passing of time" sounds wrong to me, and I'm a native speaker. "Passing" seems to be missing an article. Are you sure option b was not "testifies for **the**"?

Comment: @sumelic --> probably.

Comment: Very often when these type of multiple choice questions appear on this site, and none of the answers really fit, there is a typographical error. Please, triple-check that you copied everything correctly, and triple-check that the answer to this Q is, indeed, 'b'. Presumably you have a self-study book with the answers included, could you say what the title is  and its author.

Comment: Since this question is fundamentally flawed (in that it doesn't provide an option that reflects the normal wording of the statement at issue), it should probably be closed. But Peter Shor's answer is so sound and prospectively useful that I'd like to see the question remain open.

Comment: It seems like all such tests should always include "none of the above" as an option.

Answer (score 12):

All of the potential answers are wrong. This is a famous quotation from Cicero. And it is invariably translated:

> History is the witness that testifies ***to*** the passing of time.

(Or sometimes *"history is the witness of the times"*, which may be closer to what Cicero meant.)

You testify *for* or *against* somebody, but you testify *to* a fact or event. So (b) and (c) are incorrect. And *testify* is generally an intransitive verb, so (a) is incorrect. And (d) is much worse than all of the other choices.

Comment: Upvote. If someone asks you to choose 1 out of only 4 choices above, you would choose b, right?

Comment: @Rathony: either (a) or (b). While (b) might be more grammatical, (a) does a better job of conveying the intended meaning. What (b) means is essentially: *"history is in favor of letting time pass"*, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use *for* with ‘testify’, because the history is proving that the passing of the time has happened.  It is proving "for" the passing of the time.   Also, it is not possible to use *the* there without a preposition, because passing of the time is not a nominal clause, such as that clause or *wh* clause. The “passing of time” is a noun phrase.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer would get 2 downvotes. I can make it -1. Hmm...

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am not saying his way of explaining is inculpable. He has a point and that's all I care about. If he wrote "the" before history to describe *the* history in the sentence, do you find it still not good?

Comment: @Rathony   It's not just one misuse of the article but several, and "you testify TO something", but "testify FOR someone". (Perhaps "testify for something" is grammatical in some dialects, perhaps in Indian English, I don't know)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Absolutely. But the history in the sentence was personified as the witness. Why would you not agree with personification of passing of time? (Note: I upvoted Peter Shor's answer before I did this one). **After your comment edition: "History is the witness who testifies on behalf of the passing of time." Would it be grammatically incorrect?**

Comment: @Rathony  I'd say so. But Opaque said nothing of the sort, and you have rewritten the original quotation without using the preposition "for" so I don't understand the point you are making. Note also, that you correctly wrote "passing of time" without the article, unlike Opaque.

Comment: @Mari-LouA My points are 1. History is not a person who can testify. 2. History is written by someone who has the power to write it 3. The English version is a translated one. Therefore, we should not apply so strict a grammatical yardstick to it (using for in place of to) as it perfectly makes sense *at least* to me.

Comment: @Rathony I have to remind you that is not a forum where users can chatter endlessly, and I very very rarely go to "chat" on EL&U which must tell you something.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I would not appreciate your last comment. Why would you delete the 1st comment, which takes out some of the context that initiated this *chattering*? To make it look less chattery? BTW, you should have written, "You correctly wrote "passing of time" **with** the article unlike Opaque."